# Open file with File Chooser - kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

How should I use correctly the *selection* feature of the FileChooser (**def make_option2**) in order to open it using another function (**def show_selection**) ?

```
def make_option2(self):
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=50, spacing=20)
    file_choose = FileChooserIconView(on_selection=lambda x: self.show_selection(file_choose.selection))
    layout.add_widget(file_choose)
    btn = Button(text='Exit')
    btn.bind(on_press=lambda x: self.close_option2())
    layout.add_widget(btn)
    return layout

def show_selection(self, file_name):
    print(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in several ways. Here are 2 possibilities:

1. Binding to the `selection` property (triggered on every click on a file):

   ```
   file_choose = FileChooserIconView()
   file_choose.bind(selection=self.show_selection)
   ```
2. Using the `submit` event (user double clicks choice):

   ```
   file_choose = FileChooserIconView(on_submit=self.show_selection)
   ```

Defining the `show_selection()` as:

```
def show_selection(self, chooser, selection, *args):
    print('show_selection', selection)
```

allows it to be used in either approach. Note that the `selection` is always a list of file names (even if there is only one filename).

Comment: Thank you very much!